# Accessing and inputting elements into a dynamic array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to access different elements in my dynamic struct array however I can't seem to access any other element in the array besides the first.

C file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tuples.h"

void createTuple();

int main() {
    createTuple();
    return 0;
}

void createTuple(){

    int numOfTup;

    printf("How many tuples would you like to create:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &numOfTup);

    tuple_t *tuples;

    tuples = malloc(numOfTup * sizeof(char) * sizeof(int) * 3);

    if (tuples == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numOfTup; ++j) {

        printf("Enter an identifier for the Tuple: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &tuples[j].identifier);

        printf("TUPLE: %c\n",tuples[j].identifier);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            printf("Enter the value for the tuple (C:I:I:I)\n");
            if (i == 0) {
                scanf(" %c", &tuples[j].val0);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                scanf(" %d", &tuples[j].val1);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                scanf(" %d", &tuples[j].val2);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                scanf(" %d", &tuples[j].val3);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Header file for the struct

```
#ifndef TASK2_TUPLES_H
#define TASK2_TUPLES_H

struct tuple{
    char identifier[100];

    char val0;
    int val1;
    int val2;
    int val3;
};

typedef struct tuple tuple_t;


#endif //TASK2_TUPLES_H
```

I can't seem to access the struct at tuples[j] because whenever I try to run it it only saves the first set of elements.

Also whenever inputting the identifier the compiler skips the loop and does not allow me to enter any elements into the struct.

Thanks.

Comment: `identifier` is an array of 100 character, not a single character. Use `scanf(" %s", tuples[j].identifier);` instead of `scanf(" %c", &tuples[j].identifier);`.

Comment: might not be your problem but use:
`tuples = calloc(numOfTup, sizeof(tuple_t));`
instead of:
`tuples = malloc(numOfTup * sizeof(char) * sizeof(int) * 3);`

Comment: @nullp0tr Does anything in the code indicate the need for `calloc` over `malloc`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons from a logical point of view allocating an array instead of one object, from a security[1](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20060330071917) point of view multiplying in malloc.

Comment: @nullp0tr I'm not sure I agree about the logical argument, since use of `malloc` to allocate arrays is pretty ubiquitous.  The security aspect, though, I'll grant has given me some thought.  I suppose `calloc` has some mechanism to detect multiplication overflow?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons In case there's no overflow check in `calloc` then it's the implementation's fault, standard-wise your program is correct. Multiplication overflowing in `malloc` on the other side is your sole responsibility.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You allocate nowhere near enough memory. If your tuple identifier is 100 chars, you should allocate *at least* `101 * sizeof(char) + 3*sizeof(int)` bytes of memory. In practice, this might not suffice because the compiler might pad the struct to better align with memory. Thus, the real size might be greater. The safe thing to do is to allocate `sizeof(tuple_t)` bytes
2. Your `scanf` function to read the identifier reads a char, not a string. use `%s` to read string. Also, scanf expects pointers to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier, in our case, `%s` is a string, so the type should be `char *`. Thus, the parameter should be `tuples[j].identifier`, rather than `&tuples[j].identifier`

Overall:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tuples.h"

void createTuple();

int main() {
    createTuple();
    return 0;
}

void createTuple(){

    int numOfTup;

    printf("How many tuples would you like to create:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &numOfTup);

    tuple_t *tuples;

    tuples = malloc(numOfTup * sizeof(tuple_t));

    if (tuples == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < numOfTup; ++j) {

        printf("Enter an identifier for the Tuple: \n");
        scanf("%s", tuples[j].identifier);

        printf("TUPLE: %s\n",tuples[j].identifier);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            printf("Enter the value for the tuple (C:I:I:I)\n");
            if (i == 0) {
                scanf(" %c", &tuples[j].val0);
            } else if (i == 1) {
                scanf(" %d", &tuples[j].val1);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                scanf(" %d", &tuples[j].val2);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                scanf(" %d", &tuples[j].val3);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should allocate based on the size of tuple, not the size of the members therein.  Due to alignment issues, you can (and in this case it looks very probably will) have padding in the struct to make it greater than the sum of its members.

Comment: You are correct. I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Check your use of format specifiers and use of address of operator ( `&` ) for strings.

Comment: You are welcome, but double check all of your code.  Run it if necessary.  For example `printf("TUPLE: %c\n",tuples[j].identifier);` should also use a `%s` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the statement:

```
tuples = malloc(numOfTup * sizeof(char) * sizeof(int) * 3);
                           //always ==1      why?      why?
```

Should look more like:

```
tuples = malloc(numOfTup * sizeof(*tuples));
```

and:

```
scanf(" %c", &tuples[j].identifier);//wrong format specifier for string
       ^^^   ^                      //and address of ( & ) operator not needed for string.
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%s", tuples[j].identifier);
       ^^   ^
```